# Google analytics and coremetrics tags

Tags: email, google-analytics

Has anyone got any experience using google analytics and coremetrics in the same campaign email?

Comment: No, I wanted to see if anyone had experience with it. I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experimenting I have found out that you can use both core metrics and google analytics in the same URL and still track. Here is an example URL that we used

http://www.somesite.com/index.cfm/dep/mens/cat/jackets/subcat/group/909/level/3?cm_mmc_o=cmtag&utm_campaign=example&utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter

The url is an example so doesn't work.